# Sliding divs using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to give the effect using JQuery where a text slides in, stays for few seconds and then slides out and next text takes its place.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="texting" id="texting1" style="visibility:visible;">This is text 1</div>         
<div class="texting" id="texting2">This is text 2</div>
<div class="texting" id="texting3">This is text 3</div>
<div class="texting" id="texting4">This is text 4</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
    .texting
{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:300px;
    right:300px;
}
```

And here is the script

```
$n=1;
    $nm=2;
    var i = setInterval(function(){
        $("#texting"+$n).hide("drop",{direction:"up"},1000);
        $("#texting"+$nm).show("drop",{direction:"up"},2000);
        $n++; $nm++;
        if ($n==4, $nm==5)
        {$n=0;$nm=1;}
    },3000);
```

Please tell me where am doing it wrong? Thank You

Comment: @Sergio Please explain why that would make any difference :)

Comment: Why are you writing it at your own? Better to use something like http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @Sergio Yes I've tried it without $ too.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the upgraded script which finally worked for me :) I've added a new div named "texting0"

```
var n=-1;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    $("#texting"+(n+1)).show("drop",{direction:"down"},2000);
    $("#texting"+n).hide("drop",{direction:"up"},1000);
    n++;
    if (n==5)
    {
    n=0;
    $("#texting0").show("drop",{direction:"down"},1000);
    }
},5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition `if`, remove `,` and add your condition like `&&` or `||`

```
if ($n==4 && $nm==5)
{
   $n=0;$nm=1;
}
```

Also `increment` the same number you are using, they are `$n` and `$nm` not `n` and `nm`

like,

```
 $n++;$nm++;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yRKH/)

Comment: Thank you but that didn't make any difference

Comment: Text 1 which is visible, slides out but new one doesn't come :(

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS from:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

to:

```
display:none;
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/qyjsq/

(also you need jquery-ui for this animation: `$("#texting"+$n).hide("drop",{direction:"up"},1000);`, which you had)

Comment: And do the proposed fixes from @RohanKumar

Comment: Yes I have jquery-ui included.

Comment: You will see that there is a glitch with the endless rotation loop as the 4th div is always visible after it was displayed at the first time

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understood what was the expected behaviour. I done an example that text appears from below, stops a while and then disappears rising to very top.

I changed a little your code, hope I can help with something. I doesn't posted the code on fiddle because I don't know for you guys, but fiddle isn't fine here(very low with bad gateway errors).

Here's the JS. I've used `animate` and `delay` function insted of `hide` and `show`:

```
var n=0;
var i = setInterval(function(){
    $('.texting').eq(n).css({display:'inline-block'}).animate({top:100, opacity:1}, 1000, function(){
        $(this).delay(1000).animate({top:0, opacity:0}, 1000, function() {
            $(this).css({display:'none', top:300});
        });
    });
    n++;
    if (n == $(".texting").length) { n = 0; }
}, 3000);
```

Just removed the `visibility` property(I just use it on very especific cases), and added the `opacity` for better effect:

```
.texting
{
    display:none;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    right:300px;
}
```

Using the power of the selectors, I've remove the `id`s:

```
<div class="texting">This is text 1</div>         
<div class="texting">This is text 2</div>
<div class="texting">This is text 3</div>
<div class="texting">This is text 4</div>
```

My code is changing the `top` property. I don't if it will create scrollbars on your page. If you have problem with that, I believe and `div` wrapping the texts may work.